# dynamic radio button options for multiple questions, sending bad array data

Tags: php, database, forms, radio-button

I have a form to be used for surveys.  The questions are in one table and possible response (pr) are in another.  When a response is given a pr field, pr_count, will be increased by one.

Problem is, on form input line I have tried different methods to get an array.
currently the array I get is :

```
survey => 1
1 => 3
2 => 4
submitted => submitted
confirm => Submit Survey
```

All I need is `1=>3` and `2=>4`  That would be question 1 answer was pr_id 3  Perfect!  how do I get this without the survey, submitted and confirm ? `

```
echo '<form method="post"action="/survey1">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="survey" value="'.$survey.'">';
while ($i <= $qcount){
    //query gets questions  for a particular survey 
    $stmt = $link->prepare('SELECT question_num, survey_question.question_text as question, survey_question.question_id
    FROM survey_question
    WHERE survey_id = ?
    AND question_num = ?
    ORDER BY survey_question.question_num');
    $stmt->execute(array($survey, $i));
        while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) { 
            echo $row['question'] . "<br>";
    //query gets possible responses
                $stmt2 = $link->prepare('SELECT question_num, pr_num, survey_question.question_id, survey_pr.pr_text as possible, pr_id 
                FROM survey_question, survey_pr 
                WHERE survey_id = ?
                AND question_num = ?
                AND survey_question.question_id = survey_pr.question_id 
                ORDER BY survey_question.question_num, pr_id');
                $stmt2->execute(array($survey, $i));
                    while ($row2 = $stmt2->fetch()) {   
                    $qid = $row2['question_id'];
                    $prid= $row2['pr_id'];

                        echo  '<input type="radio" name="'.$qid.'" value="'. $prid .'">'.$row2['possible'].'<br> ';

            }
            }
        $i++;   
            }

    echo '<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted"/>';
    echo '<input name="confirm" type="submit" class="button" value="Submit Survey"/>';
```

Comment: echo  '<input type="radio" name="'.$qid.'" value="'. $prid .'">'.$row2['possible'].'<br> ';

Comment: Trying to explain this better  The form bring up question with possible responses, while loops displays next question with possible response.  I need the submitted value for if statement.  and submit is obvious.  I have never not just named by radio button something.

Comment: Sorry, but the code sample makes your question even less clear. Is your query returning a row for `submitted`, `confirm`, etc?

Comment: Side note: You do have a closing `</form>` tag, right?

Answer (score 0):

The result array you get is the whole form you have submitted (all the input fields).

So, to remove `survey => 1` from the resulting array you need to remove line #2 from your example:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="survey" value="'.$survey.'">';
```

Values `submitted => submitted` and `confirm => Submit Survey` come from the two last lines of your example:

```
echo '<input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="submitted"/>';
echo '<input name="confirm" type="submit" class="button" value="Submit Survey"/>';
```

In order to keep all the data from the survey without any additional fields, you can remove unused hidden inputs and use submit button without `name` property, like this:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="/survey1">';
while ($i <= $qcount) {
    // your loop as is
}
echo '<input type="submit" class="button" value="Submit Survey" />';
echo '</form>';
```

Comment: Thank you, however I need to capture the survey number and need to know if the form was submitted for the if statement to work.   I don't understand why I am having such a problem with this.  If I change the name='question[]' then I can only select one radio button across both questions.

Comment: Okay, if I get it right you just need to filter your resulting array to keep only `question_id => pr_id`, right? You can do it with [array-filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function:

Comment: Like this:
`$questions = array_filter($post, 'is_int', ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);` where `$post` is your resulting array with POST data